# Mathematical Model for a Pendulum in an Electric Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, models

I am studying Higher Level Physics and for my Physics IA I am doing an experiment determining the effect of the voltage between two parallel plates on the on the frequency of a pendulum in between the two plates (the pendulum has a ball made of aluminium attached to it, making it a conductor) I have an excel model for this, however I am struggling to create a concrete mathematical model for the frequency of a pendulum as a function of the voltage between the two parallel plates. I tried $2^{nd}$ order differential equations, but got lost and the units didn't make sense.

I know the frequency is affected by gravitational fields, which is given by

$$f=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt\frac{g}{L}$$

and there is an electric force also acting on the ball (the magnitude of the electric force will change based on which part of the pendulum cycle the ball is at). However, I don't know how to combine the effects of both gravitational and electric field - especially as the effect from both fields isn't constant.

My teacher said that the answer is Fourier Series, however he wasn't sure. Is this the correct way to approach the problem and if so how would I go about using this (I haven't learnt Fourier Series but I have summer break and am happy to learn)? If not, is there another way for this to work?

(I know I don't need a mathematical model for the IA but this is more for my own curiosity)

[Experiment Data and Set Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuPg6.jpg)

Comment: I doubt you’ll need fourier. Getting the equation I described first, then can learn more about frequency responses

Comment: Interesting problem

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple 1D model that takes into account the force of gravity, the force acting on a charge in an electric field and the coefficient of recovery of the velocity of a pendulum upon impact. It is assumed that at the initial moment the ball is in contact with a positively charged plate. The ball receives a charge of $q=CV$, $C$ is the capacity of the ball, which we evaluate as $C=4\pi\epsilon _0 R_0$. Here $\epsilon _0=8.8541878128*10^{-12}$, $R_0$ is the radius of the ball. The ball moves toward the oppositely charged plate, upon colliding with which it receives a charge of the opposite sign $q=-CV$. The speed of the ball after the collision is $u_1=-ku_0$, $u_0$ is the ball speed before impact, $k\le 1$ the coefficient of recovery of the velocity. Basic equation of the model is
$$\frac {d^2x}{dt^2}=-\omega _0^2x+\frac {qE}{m}$$
$\omega_0=\sqrt {g/l}$ is frequency of free oscillations of the pendulum $m$ is mass. The electric field is estimated as $E=\Delta V/d$, $d$ is the distance between the plates. I wrote a program for Mathematica 12 to find $x(t)$ and oscillation frequency depending on $V$. Figure 1 shows $x(t)$ for $V=6400, 9000$ and the dependence of frequency on $V$ at $k=0.9$.
[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 0):

The equation of motion is determined only by the forces that are perpendicular to the string. Get $F_{perp}=ma_{perp}$ first, then once you have the equation right you can figure out frequency. A string can only provide force along its own direction (as tension). It doesn’t affect perpendicular components of forces.

The dependent variable is $\theta$, and the goal is to get the force component from gravity perpendicular to the string, and the electric force component perpendicular to the string... both in terms of $\theta$.

For gravity: $F_{perp} = mg ~ sin(\theta)$

For the field, write everything you can in terms of $\theta$, like how far away you are and what angle the force is acting. Let’s say the force is horizontal, and the magnitude of it depends on how far the ball is from the plate.

$$F_{perp, ~elect}= F_{horiz}~cos(\theta)$$

$$F_{perp} = ~ [ F_{perp,~grav}] ~ + ~ [F_{perp,~elect}]$$
$$F_{perp}= ~ [mg ~ sin(\theta)] ~ + ~ [F_{horiz}~cos(\theta)]$$

Now we need to get the magnitude of the electrical or magnetic force, $F_{horiz}$, in terms of $\theta$ and plug that in. Make sure the signs work in one direction (sometimes they flip as the pendulum goes through the bottom, so sign would have to flip if so). The gravitational force sign works, as $\theta<0 \implies sin(\theta)<0$.   If the force is not horizontal that’s fine, we’re still going for an equation for $F_{perp}(\cdot)$ as $F_{perp}(\theta)$, even if there are constants and distances (or whatever) in terms of $\theta$.